# Having trouble determining an algorithm for scaling the Standard Draw window using Java

Tags: java, graphics, sieve-of-eratosthenes, stddraw

For our assignment this week, we were tasked with writing the code to develop a program that uses the StdDraw library to print a series of squares that produce a graphical simulation of the Sieve of Eratosthenes, similar to the one on this wiki page:

(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)

The program itself I have working, although for numbers past 100, the squares run off the screen. I could submit the code as is, but id prefer to have the code be able to scale the program to the inputted amount of squares, although I'm having trouble divising an algorithm that correctly scales the Standard Draw Java window.

I have tried dividing the user input over 1000 and adding that to the X_MAX axis and subtracting it from the Y_MIN axis in order to create a pinch scale type method, but this wasnt perfect and i also tried making it exponential although this does not work also.

Any idea what alogrithm i could use to correctly scale the window to fit whatever number of squares the user inputs?

My code is below for anyone curious

Thanks

http://pastebin.com/L381yQUZ

Working:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGzJY.jpg
Not Working:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpVoE.jpg

Comment: Might want to post a picture of what your program looks like to give a better idea what can be worked with.

Comment: ok ill get a screen shot now

Comment: Looking at the javadoc for StdDraw you could just call setScale(...). If you know the size of each box and the size of each gap you should be able to figure out a scale value based on the size of the input.

Comment: yeah thats what i was trying to do but im having trouble coming up with an algorithm that works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like "scale" defines the user-coordinate system, so you need to calculate the dimensions of your sieve then set the coordinate system so the sieve's in the middle of it, perhaps with a bit of padding around it.

You need something like this, in the `main()` method, before you draw the squares:

```
        double columnWidth = 0.105;
        double columnCount = Math.sqrt(input);
        double sieveWidth = columnCount * columnWidth;
        double sieveHeight = sieveWidth;
        double sieveTop = 0.95;
        double sieveLeft = 0.045;
        double padding = 0.15;

        StdDraw.setXscale(sieveLeft - padding, sieveLeft + sieveWidth + padding);
        StdDraw.setYscale(sieveTop - sieveHeight - padding, sieveTop + padding);
```

Make sure you remove any other spurious calls to `setXScale()` and `setYScale()`.

Comment: thanks this works perfectly, just need to rearrange where ill put the prime numbers text output!